# Using jpegoptim with PIL in easy-thumbnails

Tags: python, django, png, jpeg, gif

I'd like to process all JPEG thumbnails generated with [easy-thumbnail](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) via [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) thru [jpegoptim](http://freecode.com/projects/jpegoptim).

Using PIL's optimization: `image.save(..,optimize=1,...)` isn't optimizing much at all.

For example:

- with PIL: 123KB
- with PIL + optimize: 112KB
- with PIL + optimize + jpegoptim: 52KB

Can anyone point me to Python examples or libraries that integrate jpegoptim?

Comment: Are you sure jpegoptim isn't changing the JPEG quality setting? Over 2x size reduction should be impossible without losing some information.

Comment: I'm using jpegoptim --strip-all. From the docs: "strip all (Comment & Exif) markers from output file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found https://github.com/thebeansgroup/smush.py which is a lossless image optimiser in Python >=2.7. I went with https://github.com/beatak/smush.py which is a fork that works for Python >= 2.5, since we are using debian stable on our server.

It uses:

- [Gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)
- [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)
- [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/)
- [pngnq](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/)

Hopefully using [pngnq](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/) multiple times on files doesn't degrade quality, we plan to run this script on all uploaded media weekly.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `thumbnail_created` signal and call external app via `subporecess.Popen`. I just realize this in my project. You can even optimize images when they uploaded using `saved_file` signal!

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/3978536) my code:

```
import subprocess
from os.path import splitext

from django.dispatch import receiver
from easy_thumbnails.signals import saved_file, thumbnail_created

@receiver(saved_file)
def optimize_file(sender, fieldfile, **kwargs):
    optimize(fieldfile.path)

@receiver(thumbnail_created)
def optimize_thumbnail(sender, **kwargs):
    optimize(sender.path)

def optimize(path):
    runString = {
        ".jpeg": u"jpegoptim -f --strip-all '%(file)s'",
        ".jpg": u"jpegoptim -f --strip-all '%(file)s'",
        ".png": u"optipng -force -o7 '%(file)s' && advpng -z4 '%(file)s' && pngcrush -rem gAMA -rem alla -rem cHRM -rem iCCP -rem sRGB -rem time '%(file)s' '%(file)s.bak' && mv '%(file)s.bak' '%(file)s'"
    }

    ext = splitext(path)[1].lower()
    if ext in runString:
        subprocess.Popen(runString[ext] % {'file': path}, shell=True)
```

`runString` taken from [trimage](http://trimage.org/). On Debian, you need to install following packages: `jpegoptim optipng pngcrush advancecomp`. Or just use another tools, such as `smush.py`.

---

I also found [this project](https://github.com/samastur/image-diet) which encapsulates code above, has gif support and better filetype recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there are any python bindings to jpegoptim. The options I can think of are:

- [write your own python bindings](http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html) (hard)
- use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) (medium)
- just call the executable using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) (easy)